# Using fitnesse, fitsharp and slim with c#

Tags: c#, fitnesse, fitnesse-slim

I'm currently working my way through the tutorial for using fitnesse with C# here http://schuchert.wikispaces.com/FitNesse.Tutorials.0.CSharp
I'm currently stuck as my code/his code doesn't work as predicted. I don't have enough knowledge in this program to successfully sort it out myself. My code for the page is:

```
!define TEST_SYSTEM {slim}
!define TEST_RUNNER {c:\Projects\fitsharp\Runner.exe}
!define COMMAND_PATTERN {%m -r fitnesse.slim.Runner, c:\Projects\fitsharp\fitsharp.dll %p}

!path c:\Projects\C_Sharp\Digital Video Recorder\Digital Video Recorder\bin\Debug\Digital Video Recorder.dll

!define COLLAPSE_SETUP {true}
!define COLLAPSE_TEARDOWN {true}

!|import|
|Digital Video Recorder|

!|Create Programs                                        |
|Name |Channel|DayOfWeek|TimeOfDay|DurationInMinutes|id? |
|House|4      |Monday   |19:00    |60               |$ID=|
```

where the paths for dll's are definitely the paths.
But when i test this it comes up with an exception:

```
System.ArgumentException: String cannot have zero length.
   at System.Reflection.Assembly._nLoad(AssemblyName fileName, String codeBase, Evidence assemblySecurity, Assembly locationHint, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, Boolean throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean forIntrospection)
   at System.Reflection.Assembly.InternalLoad(AssemblyName assemblyRef, Evidence assemblySecurity, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, Boolean forIntrospection)
   at System.Reflection.Assembly.LoadFrom(String assemblyFile)
   at fitSharp.Machine.Engine.CurrentDomain.LoadAssembly(String assemblyPath)
   at fitSharp.Machine.Engine.ApplicationUnderTest.Assemblies.AddAssembly(String assemblyName)
   at fitSharp.Machine.Application.Shell.Execute()
   at fitSharp.Machine.Application.Shell.Run(IList`1 commandLineArguments)
```

Ive been fiddling with this for a while but i cant seem to get it to work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove the space behind the comma  from:

```
!define COMMAND_PATTERN {%m -r fitnesse.slim.Runner, c:\Projects\fitsharp\fitsharp.dll %p}
```

and change the first part to fitSharp.Slim.Service.Runner (the original).